# How to secure hash key and web app made in php/mysql

Tags: php, security, web-applications, passwords

I’m thinking about creating a web app in php and MySQL.
This app will manage and store (in MySQL) sensitive, personal information, so I’m a bit worried about security.
I’m thinking on encrypting the information before storing it in the database, using php’s own openssl_encrypt().
The challenge then lies in where to save the key for this.
I was thinking about storing the key in a file that was stored in another directory than public_html, for example a parent folder.
Would this be secure and safe enough for such a solution, storing sensitive, personal information?
What if I have this hosted at Siteground for example, then their support would have access to this file?

Thanks.

Comment: “secure and safe enough” - that’s very subjective unfortunately. What are you storing (don’t actually answer that here)? My pet’s name? My name? My SSN? My medical records? Are there laws in place related to storing this information? That host [specifically says](https://www.siteground.com/viewtos/siteground_terms_of_service) that HIPAA storage is disallowed, so that’s a posture you should take into account when thinking about storing any PII. You might want to consider looking for a host that offers a BAA at least.

Comment: Also, encrypting the data in the database means no searching, at least without some additional steps and/or performance issues.

Comment: There’s a great answer here that sums up the key storage options: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/12334/86698

Answer (score 1):

According to your description i thought about the following options:

- File in Non-Public Folder: You can put the key in a file that's not in your public website folder. But, someone who can access your files, like your hosting provider, might still see it.
- Environment Variables: These are like hidden settings on your server. You can put the key there, and it's a bit safer than a file.
- Key Management Systems: These are special services that keep your key safe. Some cloud providers like AWS or Google Cloud have them.
- Vault: This is a tool for storing secrets. Even the most powerful users can't access the secrets directly.

I any case you need to conduct Penetration testing for you app regularly   the minimum is to secure Your PHP app to protect against common OWASP attacks like SQL injection and always use secure connections (HTTPS).

Remember, if you're handling sensitive data, you need to follow regulations regarding data privacy, depending on which country your production operates, like GDPR in Europe..relevant consultancy would be a good idea.